# ember.js array not being destroyed in view

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember view that is included in other views that looks a bit like this:

```
App.view = Em.View.extend
  buttons: [
    Em.Object.create
      label: 'one'
    Em.Object.create
      label: 'two'
  ]
```

The buttons array is not destroyed when the view is destroyed because it obviously does not know to do so.

Is the best option to remove this array each time by overriding the destroy method?

Answer (score 0):

I think the array is not destroyed because it is shared between all future App.view instances, (see http://codebrief.com/2012/03/eight-ember-dot-js-gotchas-with-workarounds/, chapter 6)

I'm not 100% sure though but if you define the buttons array in the init(), I think it will be removed as well as the view instance is destroyed.

```
App.View = Em.View.extend

 buttons: null
 init ->
   @buttons = [
     Em.Object.create
       label: 'one'
     Em.Object.create
       label: 'two'
  ]
```

BTW, it's recommended to capitalize view class.